# WebSocket connection closing on sending base64

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, server

I am trying to send an image between two instances of a react.js client (open on separate devices) with a node.js/webSocket server. I am currently approaching this by sending base64 to the server, but for some reason when my code gets to client.send() it closes the webSocket connection.

Here is some of my client code:

```
handleFileSelection = (event) => {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      // Convert the image file to base64-encoded string
      const base64Image = reader.result;
      console.log(base64Image);
      this.setState({ selectedImage: base64Image });

      // Send the base64-encoded image to the server
      client.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: "file selection",
        selectedImage: base64Image,
        boundingBoxes: []
      }));
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  renderUploadPhotoButton = () => {
    return (
      <button>
        <label htmlFor='fileUpload'>
          <input
            type="file"
            id='fileUpload'
            hidden
            onChange={(event) => this.handleFileSelection(event)}
          />
          Upload Photo
        </label>
      </button>
    )
  }

componentDidMount() {
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
      const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
      console.log('got reply! ', dataFromServer);
      if (dataFromServer.type === "file selection") {
        this.setState({ 
          selectedImage: dataFromServer.selectedImage,
          boundingBoxes: dataFromServer.boundingBoxes })
      } 
    };
```

Here is some of my server code:

```
wsServer.on('request', function (request) {
    var userID = getUniqueID();
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Recieved a new connection from orgin ' + request.origin + ".");

    const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    clients[userID] = connection;
    console.log('connected: ' + userID + ' in ' + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(clients));

    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        console.log('Received Message: ', message.utf8Data);
  
        // broadcasting message to all connected clients
        for(key in clients) {
          clients[key].sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
          console.log('sent Message to: ', clients[key]);
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

The only thing I know is working is the file upload. Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to this and very lost.

The following is what I originally had for the client. It works if both instances of the client are running on the same device, but not otherwise.

```
handleFileSelection = (event) => {
    var file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    console.log(file);
    this.setState({ selectedImage: file });

    client.send(JSON.stringify({
      type: "file selection",
      selectedImage: file,
      boundingBoxes: []
    }));
  }

componentDidMount() {
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
      const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
      console.log('got reply! ', dataFromServer);
      if (dataFromServer.type === "file selection") {
        this.setState({ 
          selectedImage: dataFromServer.selectedImage,
          boundingBoxes: dataFromServer.boundingBoxes })
      } 
    };
```

Update: I think it may have something to do with the size of the base64 file. I tried sending a blob instead, but that had the same issue. Here is the client code for that:

```
handleFileSelection = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
  
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
      console.log(blob);
  
      client.send(blob);
    };
  
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };

client.onmessage = (message) => {
      if (message instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        console.log(dataFromServer);
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(dataFromServer);
        this.setState({ 
          selectedImage: blobUrl,
          boundingBoxes: [] })
      }
}
```

And here is the added server code:

```
} else if (message.type === 'binary') {
        const binaryData = message.binaryData;

        // broadcasting binary data to all connected clients
        for (key in clients) {
          for (const key in clients) {
            clients[key].sendBytes(binaryData);
            console.log('Sent Binary Data to: ', clients[key]);
        }
        }
    }
```

If I send the blob is JSON (as follows) it goes through but is received as an empty object.

```
client.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: "file selection",
        blob: blob,
        boundingBoxes: []
      }));
```

UPDATE: It is a size issue. I tried splitting the base64 string into chunks and it is now sending, being received, and displaying. Sorta. It is only putting the chunks back together on one end. Not sure what is going on.

Here is my changed client code:

```
reader.onloadend = () => {
      // Convert the image file to base64-encoded string
      const base64Image = reader.result;
      console.log(base64Image);
      this.setState({ selectedImage: base64Image });
  
      // Split the base64 string into chunks
      const chunkSize = 1024; // Adjust the chunk size as needed
      const totalChunks = Math.ceil(base64Image.length / chunkSize);
  
      // Send each chunk to the server
      for (let i = 0; i <= totalChunks; i++) {
        const chunk = base64Image.substr(i * chunkSize, chunkSize);
        client.send(JSON.stringify({
          type: "file chunk",
          chunk,
          chunkIndex: i,
          totalChunks
        }));
      }
    };
  
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

componentDidMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    };
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
        const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
        if (dataFromServer.type === "file chunk") {
          const { chunk, chunkIndex, totalChunks } = dataFromServer;
          console.log('got chunk! ', chunkIndex, ' out of ', totalChunks);
      
          // Store the received chunk
          this.updateReceivedChunks(chunkIndex, chunk);

          // Check if all chunks have been received
          if (chunkIndex === totalChunks-1) {
            console.log('Recieved all image chunks');
            // Concatenate the chunks to reconstruct the base64 image
            const base64Image = this.state.receivedChunks.join('');

            // Handle the complete base64 image here
            console.log("Reassembled incoming image chunks. ", base64Image);
            this.setState({ 
              selectedImage: base64Image,
              boundingBoxes: [] })

            // Clear the received chunks array for future use
            this.setState({ receivedChunks: [] });
          }
        }
    };
    
  }

  updateReceivedChunks = (chunkIndex, chunk) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedChunks = [...prevState.receivedChunks];
      updatedChunks[chunkIndex] = chunk;
      return { receivedChunks: updatedChunks };
    });
  };
```

Well. I'm not sure what was doing that and it may come back to haunt us, but I changed the condition for reassembly from recievedChunks.length === totalChunks to the chunkIndex === totalChunks and it seems to have fixed that issue.

Comment: Please don't use Markdown syntax in JavaScript to highlight issues, use *comments*. You're just rendering otherwise valid code as nothing but syntax errors.